# ASP.Net PreSendRequestHeaders unable to access session

Tags: asp.net, redirect

The goal is to intercept when user code calls `Response.Redirect` and alter the URL the browser is being redirected to. To alter this URL, I need access to Session (stored in Session is information that tells me what I should put in this URL.) Mostly I'm just appending a query argument to the redirect location under a circumstance.

`PreSendRequestHeaders` does let me alter `Response.RedirectLocation`. That's fine. However, I'm unable to access Session state from here. It's apparently been released before this event is fired.

So, I need a way to get this information into `PreSendRequestHeaders`; or I need another way to accomplish this. Ultimately my goal is to just append an argument to the query string of wherever the browser is being redirected.

Comment: Why you do not follow the easy way - to make the redirect from the start with the parameters you like ?

Comment: Because I am not always in control of what code initiates a redirect?

Answer (score 2):

If you can modify the code that writes to Session then you can use `Context.Items`.

For example, before the `Response.RedirectPermanent` method existed, I used the following:

```
//in some library
public static void PermanentRedirect(this HttpContext context, string url)
{
    context.Items["IsPermanentRedirect"] = true;
    context.Response.Redirect(url);
}

//in global.asax
void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Response.IsRequestBeingRedirected && (bool) (Context.Items["IsPermanentRedirect"] ?? false))
    {
        Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
    }
}
```